# Nginx Proxy pass to S3 after basic auth not working

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

## Nginx proxy to S3 bucket

I have a nginx proxy to an S3 bucket through Linode.

### This config is working fine

My Nginx config is working fine when basic auth is disabled, like this.
(Please ignore for now that some configuration is duplicate, I do this because I want to disable auth_basic for /api and /images later on). Feel free however to respond without duplicate lines.

```
location /api {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://mydomainhere.eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /images {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://mydomainhere.eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/images;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://mydomainhere.eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

### This config does not work

```
location /api {
        auth_basic off; # ADDED THIS LINE
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://mydomainhere.eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_ignore_headers    Authorization; # ADDED THIS LINE
        proxy_hide_header    Authorization; # ADDED THIS LINE
}

location /images {
        auth_basic off; # ADDED THIS LINE
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://mydomainhere.eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/images;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_ignore_headers    Authorization; # ADDED THIS LINE
        proxy_hide_header    Authorization; # ADDED THIS LINE
}

location / {
        auth_basic           "Restricted Access"; # ADDED THIS LINE
        auth_basic_user_file {MY_PATH_HERE};  # ADDED THIS LINE
    
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://mydomainhere.eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_ignore_headers    Authorization; # ADDED THIS LINE
        proxy_hide_header    Authorization; # ADDED THIS LINE
}
```

The basic auth is working fine. Im asked for a password when accessing `/` and **not** asked for a password when accessing `api/` and `images/`.  I also get a valid response from `api/api.json` when not authenticated through basic auth.

### The problem

The problem is that I get a 400 error when I login through basic auth (**on each endpoint, which I access thereafter**). Somehow I think the basic auth headers that are appended are send to S3, which I try to disable with:

```
proxy_ignore_headers    Authorization; 
proxy_hide_header    Authorization;
```

As shown in the example above. But this has no effect.

### Debug information

The headers that are send from the browser to nginx are (without basic auth enabled):

```
:authority: mydomainhere
:method: GET
:path: /api/api.json
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8
cache-control: max-age=0
if-modified-since: Wed, 22 Mar 2023 13:18:15 GMT
if-none-match: "2bcd098e106ce6a7b9961217c965127c"
sec-ch-ua: "Brave";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-gpc: 1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

The headers that are send from the browser to nginx are (**WITH** basic auth enabled):

```
:authority: mydomainhere
:method: GET
:path: /api/api.json
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8
authorization: Basic somekeyhere
cache-control: max-age=0
if-modified-since: Wed, 22 Mar 2023 13:18:15 GMT
if-none-match: "2bcd098e106ce6a7b9961217c965127c"
sec-ch-ua: "Brave";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-gpc: 1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

This line gets added:

**authorization: Basic somekeyhere**

### Conclusion and question

I want to achieve that people do login with basic auth when they access my site on `/`. My site is a static site hosted on Linode (Object storage on S3). I don´t want the folders `/images/` and `/api` protected with basic auth. How do I achieve this with NGINX? and take in mind the things that I have tried above.

### Extra information

My nameservers and domain go through cloudflare, I don´t think Cloudflare has anything to do with it, but to be sure I mention this. I have `skipped` the protection from cloudflare on the (sub)domain itself, since it is protected by basic auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing:

```
proxy_ignore_headers    Authorization; 
proxy_hide_header    Authorization;
```

for:

```
proxy_set_header Authorization "";
```